# Placing a widget inside a DIV

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer

I have a div.

```
<div class="left_panel box animate fadeInLeft three" id="layers"  style="display:none;">
            <div class="sidebar-head">
                <h2>layers</h2>
                <div>Content Here</div>
                <div class="tab-close"> < </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Inside this Div I want my LayerControl widget to be placed.

```
layerControl: {
            include: true,
            id: 'layerControl',
            type: 'domNode',
            srcNodeRef: 'layerTOC',
            path: 'gis/dijit/LayerControl', 
            title: 'Layers',
            open: true,
            position: 0,
            options: {
            map: true,
            layerControlLayerInfos: true,
            separated: true,
            vectorReorder: true,
            overlayReorder: true,
                               layerInfos: [
                                      {
                            layer: cities,
                            type: 'dynamic',
                            title: 'i18n.viewer.operationalLayers.cities',
            controlOptions: {
            noZoom:false,
            swipe:false
 }
 }
            ]}
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use this:

`srcNodeRef: 'layerTOC',`

with a domNode widget, you need an HTML element with that target ID (layerTOC). So your HTML should look something like this:

`<div class="left_panel box animate fadeInLeft three" id="layers"  style="display:none;">
    <div class="sidebar-head">
        <h2>layers</h2>
        <div id="layerTOC">Content Here</div>
        <div class="tab-close"> < </div>
    </div>
</div>`

and the element `<div id="layerTOC">Content Here</div>` will be replaced by the widget.